# Upgrade RaspberryPi from 19.10 to 20.04 fails to boot after successful upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi (3) with Ubuntu 19.10 arm64 installed. I successfully upgraded it to 20.04 via `do-release-upgrade` and then restarted. Nothing. It doesn't get past the rainbow graphic. However, this is not a problem with 20.04, because if I flash the 20.04 image to the card, there is no problem. What could be the problem with the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the Ubuntu OS installer does not update the `config.txt` file in `/boot/firmware` (the `system-boot` partition) - this gets updated between releases, but apparently not by the installer during upgrade (although the OS expects it). This means that after upgrade, it is no longer valid and the system cannot boot.

The 20.04 one looks like this:

```
# Please DO NOT modify this file; if you need to modify the boot config, the
# "usercfg.txt" file is the place to include user changes. Please refer to
# the README file for a description of the various configuration files on
# the boot partition.

# The unusual ordering below is deliberate; older firmwares (in particular the
# version initially shipped with bionic) don't understand the conditional
# [sections] below and simply ignore them. The Pi4 doesn't boot at all with
# firmwares this old so it's safe to place at the top. Of the Pi2 and Pi3, the
# Pi3 uboot happens to work happily on the Pi2, so it needs to go at the bottom
# to support old firmwares.

[pi4]
kernel=uboot_rpi_4.bin
max_framebuffers=2

[pi2]
kernel=uboot_rpi_2.bin

[pi3]
kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin

[all]
arm_64bit=1
device_tree_address=0x03000000

# The following settings are "defaults" expected to be overridden by the
# included configuration. The only reason they are included is, again, to
# support old firmwares which don't understand the "include" command.

enable_uart=1
cmdline=nobtcmd.txt

include syscfg.txt
include usercfg.txt
```

Obviously, this needs to be updated *after* you update the OS, but *before* you reboot. If you don't, you can always do it manually with the SD card, and it will still work fine.